# Remove non-constant duplicate words from strings in an array\list

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I'm trying to extract primary words from a large set of very long strings to simplify displaying it so...

Assuming we have a string array that outputs:

```
Something One
Something [ABC] Two
Something [ABC] Three
Something Four Section 1
Something Four Section 2
Something Five
```

How to remove the `non-constant` duplicate words like `Something` and `[ABC]` so that it only leaves the unique identifiers of each string like `One` `Two` `Three` and output this list:

```
One
Two
Three
Four Section 1
Four Section 2
Five
```

Knowing that:

- A duplicate is; any word that repeats more than once in the list
- {"One", "Two", "Three", ..} as said, are not constant and are just there for the example and could change to anything else like for example {"Alpha" "Bravo", "Charlie"} or {"Nu", "Xi", "Pi"} long as they don't repeat.
- If a certain word exist (in this case) "Section 1", the word before stays with it So that "Something Four Section 1" would become "Four Section 1"

Comment: Since string is immutable every time you modify the string a new string will be created so they will always be left as they are

Comment: Shouldn't `Four` also be removed?

Comment: Your example treats `Four` and `[ABC]` differently. How does the algorithm know which of them to remove and which one to keep?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, i think he has a list of which words to remove

Comment: @Explisam: please [edit] your question and make it more clear what you want. How do you decide what to remove and what to retain?

Comment: Yeah i didn't explain this part well, so Four can be resolved or skipped if a certain word comes after it like "Section" which is always a fixed phrase.

Comment: @EmrahSüngü I want to create a whole new list, modifying the values and not changing the source.

Comment: @Explisam You must provide a whole set of word or phrases that you want to remove and other constraints like the one of the word "Four". We can't enter in your mind.

Comment: Are the words separated by " " only?

Comment: @EmrahSüngü what exactly are you referring to?

Comment: @Explisam Is this also possible in the string "Something, Five" or "Something; Five" or "Something - Five"

Comment: @EmrahSüngü Yes, it could be.

Comment: @Explisam, Then how do you expect to find duplicate words if any kind of data entry is possible??

Comment: @EmrahSüngü Special chars or separators are not the problem as they're going to be filtered before this process goes which leaves us with spaces as the only separator.

Comment: @EmrahSüngü I'm sorry, you asked a question and i answered then you replied with an irrelevant topic that can be solved with a simple filter, yet you identified it as an insolvable problem. Why am i to blame?

Comment: @EmrahSüngü and to add, i only confirmed because i thought that might help with your solution, so please reconsider your questions.

Comment: Is the following possible → Something Four Section 1 Five Section 2

Comment: @EmrahSüngü No, each string has at least 1 duplicate (Something, [ABC]) and 1 unique identifier (One, Two, ..ect)

Comment: @EmrahSüngü If you mean the sections being parted on 2 different identifiers or numbers then no. Section only comes after at least 2 of the same identifier or number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution assumes you know nothing (just like John Snow) except the certain words such as `Section 1"`. It works for arbitrary string input. It has 2 main points.

1) `FindRepeatedWords` is a method which fills up `UniqueWords` hashset and `Repeats` hashset. UniqueWords, as the name suggests is the everyunique word in the list and Repeats are repeated words.

2)`CleanUpWordsAndDoNotChangeList` is the main method which does what you want. It decides to remove the words based on certain words.

```
namespace StackOverfFLow {

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    internal class Program {
        private static readonly HashSet<string> UniqueWords = new HashSet<string>();
        private static readonly HashSet<string> Repeats = new HashSet<string>();
        private static readonly List<string> CertainWords = new List<string> { "Section 1", "Section 2" };
        private static readonly List<string> Words = new List<string> { "Something One", "Something [ABC] Two", "Something [ABC] Three", "Something Four Section 1", "Something Four Section 2", "Something Five" };

        private static void Main(string[] args) {
            FindRepeatedWords();
            var result = CleanUpWordsAndDoNotChangeList();
            result.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Cleans Up Words And Des oNot Change List.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static List<string> CleanUpWordsAndDoNotChangeList() {
            var newList = new List<string>();
            foreach(var t in Words) {
                var sp = SeperateStringByString(t);
                for(var index = 0; index < sp.Count; index++) {
                    if(Repeats.Contains(sp[index]) != true) { continue; }
                    var fixedTocheck = sp.ElementAtOrDefault(index + 1);
                    if(fixedTocheck == null || CertainWords.Contains(fixedTocheck)) { continue; }
                    sp.RemoveAt(index);
                    index = index - 1;
                }
                newList.Add(string.Join(" ", sp));
            }
            return newList;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Finds Unique and Repeated Words.
        /// </summary>
        private static void FindRepeatedWords() {
            foreach(var eachWord in Words) {
                foreach(var element in SeperateStringByString(eachWord)) {
                    if(UniqueWords.Add(element) == false) { Repeats.Add(element); };
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Seperates a string by another string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="source">Source string</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static List<string> SeperateStringByString(string source) {
            var seperatedStringByString = new List<string>();
            foreach(var certainWord in CertainWords) {
                var indexOf = source.IndexOf(certainWord);
                if(indexOf <= -1) { continue; }
                var a = source.Substring(0, indexOf).Trim().Split(' ');
                seperatedStringByString.AddRange(a);
                seperatedStringByString.Add(certainWord);
            }
            if(seperatedStringByString.Count < 1) { seperatedStringByString.AddRange(source.Split(' ')); }
            return seperatedStringByString;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to modify it to detect any duplicates regardless word position but anyways thank you that was very helpful.

Comment: @Explisam, I am glad i was helpful. I had to make some assumptions because your question was too broad :) Nice question ,nice practice! thanks

Comment: I'm not sso good with explaining things, not to mention in a different language.

Answer (score 0):

I`m not sure is it this you want but I will past my code.

Fast code:

```
        string itemName = "";
        List<string> destinationArray = new List<string>();

        List<string> inputArrayList = new List<string>();
        inputArrayList.Add("Something One");
        inputArrayList.Add("Something [ABC] Two");
        inputArrayList.Add("Something [ABC] Three");
        inputArrayList.Add("Something Four Section 1");
        inputArrayList.Add("Something Four Section 2");
        inputArrayList.Add("Something Five");
        inputArrayList.Add("Other Text");

        List<string> allWordList = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in inputArrayList)
        {
            allWordList.AddRange(item.Split(' ').ToList());
        }

        List<string> searchingArrayList = new List<string>();
        searchingArrayList = allWordList.GroupBy(x => x)
                    .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
                    .Select(group => group.Key).ToList();

        foreach (var itemInput in inputArrayList)
        {
            itemName = itemInput;
            foreach (var itemSearching in searchingArrayList)
            {
                itemName = itemName.Replace(itemSearching, "");
            }
            destinationArray.Add(itemName);
        }

        destinationArray.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: @Explisam it`s working but you have to refactoring this. If it`s ok :) you can give me accept and +1 :)